# How to get current User Name in Silverlight application without asking user to login

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I need to get current username of user who start silverlight application.
I was able to do it, when I get User.Identity.Name in aspx page and pass it to silverlight app.
But it requires windows authentication, so asks users to sign in with domain user(with same domain as iis server).

Is it possible to get windows username, without asking user to sign in, and get name even if user is in another domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You should use windows authentication within your service.